# Kawasaki GPz1100A1 blink/error codes

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-injection, kawasaki, code

Could someone please explain how to Pull blink/error codes 1984 Kawasaki GPz1100 [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

This is what the Kawasaki factory service manual says:

> Pulses of green light can be seen through the inspection hole in the control unit. Arrangement of long and short pulses express the trouble codes which correspond to the faults.

The DFI control unit keeps faults in memory and keeps emitting trouble codes until the ignition is turned off. Said inspection hole is located next to the DFI control unit connector.

This is how to read the codes:

| Pulse Sequence | Detected Fault |
| --- | --- |
| long – short | Throttle sensor open or short |
| long – short short | Air temperature sensor open or short |
| long – short short short | Engine temperature sensor open or short |
| long long – short | Atmospheric pressure sensor open or short |
| long long – short short | Starter switch continues on after engine starts |
| long long – short short short | No ignition pulses are transmitted to control unit when cranking engine |
| long long long – short | Memories in CPU do not operate properly |

Try searching the web for the “Kawasaki GPz1100 KZ1000R Service Manual Supplement” (see page 3-5 and following in there) and also the “Kawasaki KZ1000 KZ1100 Service Manual”. You should be able to find printed and PDF copies of those.

Comment: Thanks for that but I already have that information.. my service manual tells me how to decipher the flashes but what I’m asking is, how do I pull the codes..? 
as in what steps do I take to start the flashing..? I believe there’s a manual sequence to set the control unit’s green light blinking, it doesn’t just start blinking by itself..